# Basic Auth with RestyGWT Rest Services?

Tags: rest, gwt, resty-gwt

How can I set the Basic Auth user id and password when using a RestyGWT **Rest Services**?

The [RestyGWT User Guide](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html) describes how to set the user id and password used in basic authentication for the RestyGWT **REST API** but I haven't found any docs describing how to do basic auth with the RestyGWT **Rest Services**

I'm using RestyGWT v1.2

******* *UPDATE* *********
I tried the following with no luck.  The browser is still opening a prompt for User ID / Password when I call the service method.

```
final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Authorization", "Basic anJvYmPpbnKAbGl4ZXByb2N4c3OuZ29tOmpyb2JiaW6z");
final Resource workflowResource = new Resource("", headers);
((RestServiceProxy)workflowService).setResource(workflowResource);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code example provided in the question should work.  I found another person experiencing problems adding a custom header to a RestyGWT service as described in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/restygwt/1KZA3sbSMF8) to the RestyGWT group and [this bug](https://github.com/chirino/resty-gwt/issues/75) in Github.

As a temporary workaround, I'm using the @HeaderParam and passing the Base64 encoded Authorization header through the RestService method call.

```
public void getRestData(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authHeader, MethodCallback<List<Workflow>> callback);
```

Answer (score 3):

I do it using a DispatcherFilter, inside the filter method.

```
@Override
    public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder)
    {
        ....
        builder.setHeader(KEY, value);
        ....
        return true;
    }
```